# Why is finiteness required here (in Coset result)?

Tags: group-theory

I was given the following result:

> Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then the following are true.
> (i) For $x \in G$, the map $f_x : H \rightarrow Hx$ defined by $f_x(h) = hx$ is a bijection
> (ii) If $H$ is finite, then $\lvert H \rvert = \lvert Hx \rvert$

($Hx$ here is the right coset of $H$ with element $x \in G$)

My question is why is finiteness required in (ii)? Could you not define the same bijection as in (i) even if $H$ is not finite and still obtain that $\lvert H \rvert = \lvert Hx \rvert$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Since there is a bijection between $H$ and $Hx$, $|H|=|Hx|$ even if $H$ is not finite.

I guess that the result added the assumption that $H$ is finite maybe because it is used to prove Lagrange's Theorem later on. To prove Lagrange's Theorem, it needs the condition that $H$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, Lagrange's Theorem is the next result in the notes I'm reading so that could be it. Thank you.

Comment: @Alan Wang An ammendment on your final claim on how ''to prove Lagrange's Theorem" needs to be made, because it is not quite correct. Lagrange's theorem holds in general, with the statement that the cardinalities of both quotient sets via the left respectively right congruences modulo $H$ are equal to what we call the index $(G \colon H)$ and furthermore this index satisfies the relation $|G|=(G \colon H)|H|$. Absolutely no need to limit the discussion to only finite cardinals.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Normally the Lagrange's Theorem introduced in reference book will restrict $H$ to be finite. You may refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). But of course your view is correct also.

Comment: @Alan Wang It depends on the kind of textbook one takes as a reference. Treatises which are written from a deep and overall comprehensive perspective will introduce Lagrange's theorem in general version from the very beginning. My personal contention is that results should be viewed in their highest degree of generality, without introducing unessential hypotheses (such as finiteness here) and without cowering away from handling general cardinals when it is not merely possible, but actually when the context intrinsically calls for them (arbitrary cardinals).